# excel-reader utf problem

Tags: php, phpexcel

Can you help me with problem writtent below:

I am getting error ***iconv() [function.iconv]: Detected an illegal character in input string*** when i am reading xls file and converting it into csv. I am using [php-excel-library](http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/downloads/list) and i get this error in line:

```
case 'iconv' :    
     $result = iconv('UTF-16LE', $this->_defaultEncoding, $string);
break;
```

Does enybody know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that in your file is a bit-sequence that cannot be mapped onto a char, b/c it's meaningless, and therefore not be converted to another encoding.

Use the //IGNORE-flag as descriped [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php).

Comment: i also try this with no success

Answer (score 0):

Be sure the file is UTF-16LE encoded as trying to import the wrong format will throw those kinds of errors.

Use PHP 5.3 or greater, as PHP < 5.3 cannot handle UTF-16 encoding (check the notes here: [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php))

Instead of ignore you may want to try //TRANSLIT to have iconv convert the character to one that is compatible in your default encoding (eg, convert MS "fancy quotes" to regular single/double quotes in ascii)

Comment: I have installed php 5.3.8 and I tried //TRANSLIT, and it doesn't work

Comment: Have you been able to identify the offending character?  Try debugging to find out what line of the file it's on and narrow down what character is bad. That was my first step in figuring it out. If you can find the offending character(s) you might be able to track down what the problem with the encoding is.